# Plone custom template for content type

Tags: plone

Iam new to Plone. I followed the link http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-a-content-type-for-plone-3-for-developers and i added dvd content type. When i extend it by using http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-a-custom-template-for-a-plone-content-type, custom template is not showing.Iam getting the error as

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.Five.browser.metaconfigure, line 476, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 107, in pt_render
   - Warning: Compilation failed
   - Warning: zope.tal.taldefs.TALError: bad TAL attribute: u'', at line 27, column 4
PTRuntimeError: ['Compilation failed', "zope.tal.taldefs.TALError: bad TAL attribute: u'', at line 27, column 4"]
```

I know i made some mistake. I dont know whats that.Anyone help me?!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error :

```
Warning: zope.tal.taldefs.TALError: bad TAL attribute: u'', at line 27, column 4
```

It says that you have an attributes u'' that have nothing to do in a tal expression. Maybe something like

```
tal:attributes="u''"
```

somewhere in your template...